# Not calculating "set" correctly - syntax?

Tags: set, netlogo

I am trying to use set to calculate a value, but it always return 0.5.  When I breakdown the equation to individual operators, it works fine, but when I put it all together, all I get is 0.5.  I think I have a syntax misunderstand.  Any suggestions?

```
to go
;;see if a new risk is generated [randomly]
if random 2 = 1  ;;50% chance risk be generated on an individual project
[
    make-risk

ask one-of projects
  [
    ask one-of risks [
      set risk-encounter ((((RE-influence * ( [duration] of myself ) * 0.5)) / (( [duration] of myself ))))  ;;calculate RE. THIS DOES NOT WORK :-(  Always sets to 0.5
      set temp-RE-score risk-encounter
    ]
      set total-RE total-RE + temp-RE-score ;;update the project's RE score        
  ]
]
ask projects[
  set label precision total-RE 1
  set size total-RE / 10 ; size according to RE score
]


tick   

if ticks >= (max [duration] of projects ) * 2 [stop]  ;; stops all the projects once max duration is reached (* 2)
```

end

Comment: What is the value of RE-influence? The `[duration] of myself` parts will cancel out so risk-encounter will be RE-influence * 0.5. You can also do print statements like `print [duration] of myself' just before the problem line to work out the values going into the equation.

Comment: Jake, you don't need so many parentheses, btw.  There's at least one completely unnecessary set of parentheses on each side of  `/`.  Some of the other parentheses are optional, but might be desirable.  Other than that, I'm not sure what there is about the syntax of the `set` expression that you could be misunderstanding.  But I agree with all of Jen's advice.  If `risk-encounter` is getting the value 0.5, then `RE-influence` is 1 when this line of code runs.  One more thing: You know that `myself` refers to the `project`, right?  If you want to refer to the `risk`, use `self`.